# Charge a Lipo with only Constant-Current Stage?

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, lithium-ion

I'm following this standard algorithm:
http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries
[Algorithm for charging LI-PO batteries?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15722/algorithm-for-charging-li-po-batteries)

but am wondering if I can get ~80% of the capacity with just the constant-current stage, why not just do that?  Is there something about the constant-voltage stage that is helpful for the chemistry (knocking off dendrites and such?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited

You can stop charging when voltage reaches maximum voltage.

This is explained in article you mentioned (from Battery University):

> Li-ion does not need to be fully charged, as is the case with lead
>   acid, nor is it desirable to do so. In fact, it is better not to fully
>   charge, because high voltages stresses the battery. Choosing a lower
>   voltage threshold, or **eliminating the saturation charge** altogether,
>   prolongs battery life but this reduces the runtime. Since the consumer
>   market promotes maximum runtime, these chargers go for maximum
>   capacity rather than extended service life.

Saturation charge is used to store maximum possible charge in battery. If you want maximum service life instead of maximum capacity - this is how to do it. Eliminate saturation charge.

Im assuming you know that Li-Ion is very similar to Li-Po and same rules apply to both types.

Comment: I mean to stop the CC stage once 4.2V is acheived.  The question is whether only ever doing CC up until 4.2V is OK.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missunderstood. Should I delete this?

Comment: I would consider this as not answering the question. Adding a comment to the question about limiting voltage would be good though.

Comment: fair enough response.  i just wasn't sure if i was missing something chemically.